TitleFieldTemplate in RJSF form is ignored
I'm playing with react-jsonschema-form, trying to customize TitleFieldTemplate following an example in the documentation which apparently does not work:
https://rjsf-team.github.io/react-jsonschema-form/docs/advanced-customization/custom-templates/#titlefieldtemplate
I made a (not) working example which is basically a copy of what's on the documentation but using MUI theme, to show that it does not work, at least to me.
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/7nkpjn
Anybody can bring a bit of light to it?
